# Drools - Unable to create Resource to load into KieContainer

Tags: scala, akka, drools, kie

I'm using the following chunk of code in Scala to create a KieContainer out of which I create a new KieSession:

```
val kieSession = DroolsMgt.getKieSession(List("myFile.drl"), Boot.kieServices){
   val kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem()
    for (filename <- drlFiles) {
      val fis = new FileInputStream(filename)
      kfs.write(filename, kieServices.getResources.newInputStreamResource(fis))
    }

    val kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll()

    val kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository.getDefaultReleaseId)

    kieContainer.newKieSession()
}
```

This code has been working just fine when run in a Drools-only project, however now that I'm integrating it within a larger project involving an Actor system etc. I'm getting a `null` value when trying to use my drl file as a Resource by calling `kieServices.getResources.newInputStreamResource(fis)`.

As a result, no files are being loaded into my KieContainer and no KiePackages are being created within the KieBase, meaning that no rules will fire at any time (even blank ones with no "when" conditions).

What could be causing the the KieResources to return a null? Are there any dependencies or imports to look out for?

EDIT:
I'm also running the following code to verify the contents of the DRL file being read. It's printed out as expected but the Resource is still a `null` in the end.

```
println("FIS Contents =\t" + sBuilder.toString())
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename)
println("DRL Source = \n")
source.getLines().foreach(x => println(x))
source.close()

val fisResource = kieResources.newInputStreamResource(fis)

println("Resource = \t" + fisResource)
```

Comment: Probably a different `ClassLoader`?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, "myFile.drl" is used as a relative pathname for creating ye olde FileInputStreame. I'd check what this resolves to, or what the working directory is in the "larger project's"  fancy environment. -- As an aside, please note: Actors are apt to dissemble ;-)

Comment: I'm actually printing out the file's contents using the code added in my edit, but `val fisResource = kieResources.newInputStreamResource(fis);     println("Resource = \t" + fisResource)` still returns null for the fisResource. Does that make things any clearer? Could this still be an issue with resolving to the right working directory?